# Non-isomorphic covering spaces with same domain and range

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Suppose $X$ is a connected topological space and $p,q:\tilde X\to X$ are covering spaces of $X$. That is, for all $x\in X$ there exists an open $U\subseteq X$ containing $x$ such that $p^{-1}[U],q^{-1}[U]$ are disjoint unions of open sets in $\tilde X$ which are homeomorphic to $U$. Is there always a pair of homeomorphisms $\tilde h:\tilde X\to\tilde X$ and $h:X\to X$ such that $p\tilde h=hq$? I can see how this would not have to be the case if $X$ were disconnected, but I can't think of a counterexample where $X$ is connected.

Comment: No; consider covering maps $S^1 \to S^1$ of different degrees. The corresponding group-theoretic fact is that isomorphic subgroups need not be conjugate, even by a not-necessarily-inner automorphism.